# Lack of 'required' fields in form suggests I am not correctly associating models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm having trouble validating an input form and saving the data from that form.  I suspect that perhaps these are both caused by an association problem, though I am not sure.

I'm using CakePHP 2.2.0 RC2.

I have three models: User, Member and Address.  Each user can have several members in their account and each user can have many addresses (it remembers past addresses, too).

My model associations are:

User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {

public $name = 'User';

public $hasMany = array(
    'Member' => array(
        'className' => 'Member',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'order' => 'Member.member ASC',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
    'Address' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'order' => 'Address.address ASC',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
...
```

Member model:

```
class Member extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Member';

public $displayField = 'member';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
);
...
```

Address model:

```
class Address extends AppModel {

public $name = 'Address';

public $displayField = 'address';

public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    )
);
...
```

For my Form create statement, I have:

```
$this->Form->create( 'Member', array( 'url' => array( 'action' => 'add' ) ) );
```

I am using the Member model and controller to handle the form as it submits either only Member fields, or Member and Address fields, depending on whether the user already has an address entry or not (if the user doesn't, it adds address input fields to the form, otherwise it doesn't).

I am not submitting any User fields in the form.

Now, I would expect, if my associations were set up correctly, that any 'required' fields in any of the models would have an asterisk next to them.  There are some fields set as required in both the Member and Address models, and while the Member fields show up on the form as being required (with an asterisk), the Address fields do not.

An example of required Address field code from the Address model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'street1' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => array( 'notEmpty' ),
            'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message' => 'Please enter a street address'
        ),
....
```

And here's some of my view/form code:

```
echo $this->Form->input( 'Member.firstname', array( 'label' => 'First name', 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $this->Form->input( 'Member.middlename', array( 'label' => 'Middle name', 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $this->Form->input( 'Member.lastname', array( 'label' => 'Last name', 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo '<p class="bold">Please enter current address details:</p>';
echo $this->Form->input( 'Address.street1', array( 'label' => 'Street address (line 1)', 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $this->Form->input( 'Address.street2', array( 'label' => 'Street address (line 2)', 'type' => 'text' ) );
echo $this->Form->input( 'Address.suburb', array( 'label' => 'Suburb', 'type' => 'text' ) );
...
```

When I output $validationErrors on the form page (before form submission), I get this:

```
Array
(
    [Member] => Array
        (
        )

    [User] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

I'm assuming there should also be an [Address] section there.

I can't spot anything obvious but I'm new to CakePHP (though I do have PHP experience), so any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Peter.

Comment: So, I have an answer but I'm not sure it's a good one.  I've seen many people say that using uses() in a controller to include extra models is a bad thing. However, the 2.x cookbook lists this as being the way to include additional models.  If I add "public $uses = array( 'Member', 'Address' );" to my MembersController, the validation springs into life.  It seems to give me what I need.  I'm happy to avoid uses() if there is something "more correct" that I'm supposed to be doing in my model association but can anyone tell me what that might be?  Thanks again.

Comment: That's about the way to go. Your validation for your Address should be in the Address model. Then you can just `$this->Form->input('Address.title');` and it _should_ JustWork(tm)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you said you were using a release candidate (RC2) of Cake 2.2. There is now a stable release and I strongly encourage you to upgrade to that.

You create the form with the `Member` model but it **doesn't have a direct relation(association) to Address**. Address is associated to User. If you create the form via the User model it should work all right.

If this scenario - creating the form with the User model - doesn't work for you and your application 
logic than your Database model and your Model associations are wrong and they do not comply with your business needs. If this is the case you should consider changing the Architecture of the application.

And a note on `$uses`: you shouldn't have to include the `Address` model in your controller's $uses in order to be able to validate inputs. Controller::$uses is for use of models (other than the controller's own model) directly in the Controller itself. For example:

```
public $uses = array('Article', 'News');
```

in any controller would make all Article and News Models' methods available in that controller with:

```
$this->Article->methodName();
```

or

```
$this->News->methodName();
```